Video isn't stopping even when I open modal
I have a video tag in which I am playing some video and passing that video to my modal as a prop. When I open the modal, the video still plays in the background. I want it to be stopped when I open the modal. Below is the code
const videoRef = useRef(null);
  function pauseVideo() {
    videoRef.current.pause()
  }
function openModal(url, index) {
    setImageUrl(url);
    setActiveIndex(index);
    setIsOpen(true);
  }
                 <video
                ref={videoRef}
                 controls
                className="h-[400px] w-full mt-3  border border-white"
                onClick={() => {
                  openModal(communityImages, index);
                  pauseVideo();
                }}
              >
                <source
                  src={data?.mediaUrls[0]?.mediaUrl}
                  type="video/mp4"
                />
              </video>
    



I've refactored your code slightly to use more react good practices.
Using a state to store your video ref, will trigger a re-render if the video element is re-rendered, and updating the useCallback pauseVideo hook.
Let me know if these changes help your code work better


const [videoEl, setVideoEl] = useState(null)

const pauseVideo = useCallback(() => {
  if (videoEl) {
    videoEl.pause()
  }
}, [videoEl])

const openModal = useCallback((url, index) => {
  setImageUrl(url);
  setActiveIndex(index);
  setIsOpen(true)
}, [])

 <video
ref={setVideoEl}
 controls
className="h-[400px] w-full mt-3  border border-white"
onClick={() => {
  openModal(communityImages, index);
  pauseVideo();
}}
>
<source
  src={data?.mediaUrls[0]?.mediaUrl}
  type="video/mp4"
/>
</video>
    



